# Dropdown menu disappears when moving mouse to the dropdown options

Tags: html, css

so the issue I am having with my nav bar is that once I start dragging my mouse through the options that show up once I hover my mouse over the titles, the dropdown menu disappears once I reach the 4th row/option.

There also seems to be a gap between the nav bar and the main title sheet

Any input or help will be greatly appreciated, Thank you!

Here is the HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<!--
-->
<html>
    <head>
        <title>MACS</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no" />
        <meta name="description" content="" />
        <meta name="keywords" content="" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/main.css" />
    </head>
    <body class="is-preload">

        <!-- Wrapper -->
        <div id="wrapper">

                <nav>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href = "">Center</a>
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href = "">Central</a></li>
                                <li><a href = "">sphere</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href = "">Hub</a>
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href = "">Training</a></li>
                                <li><a href = "">lyst</a></li>
                                <li><a href = "">BIT</a></li>
                                <li><a href = "">watch</a></li>
                                <li><a href = "">Query</a></li>
                                <li><a href = "">MPR</a></li>
                                <li><a href = "">Lawsuit Reporting</a></li>
                                <li><a href = "">Sample Reports</a></li>
                                <li><a href = "">Access Request and Support</a></li>
                                <li><a href = "">Other Apps</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href = "">Client Support</a>
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href = "">Service Catalog</a></li>
                                <li><a href = "">Placeholder</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href = "">Peer Benchmarking</a>
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href = "">Peer Information and Reporting</a></li>
                                <li><a href = "">Benchmarking Guide</a></li>
                                <li><a href = "">Plan Design Summary</a></li>
                                <li><a href = "">Training</a></li>
                                <li><a href = "">FAQ</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href = "">Consultant Support</a>
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href = "">Consultant Templates</a></li>
                                <li><a href = "">Consultant Template Catalog</a></li>
                                <li><a href = "">Consultant Dashboard</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href = "">Prospect Analytics</a>
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href = "">Reference Guide</a></li>
                                <li><a href = "">Priority Log</a></li>
                                <li><a href = "">Implementation</a></li>
                                <li><a href = "">FAQ</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href = "">Book of Business</a>
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href = "">Business Management Reporting</a></li>
                                <li><a href = "">Trend</a></li>
                                <li><a href = "">Plan Monitor Report</a></li>
                                <li><a href = "">Client Master Table</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href = "">Lawsuit</a>
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href = "">Legal Resources</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href = "">Rebates and Compliance</a>
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href = "">Rebate Invoicing Solution Center</a></li>
                                <li><a href = "">Rebates Invoicing Activity Application</a></li>
                                <li><a href = "">Rebates Invoicing User Guide</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href = "">Resources</a>
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href = "">Alation</a></li>
                                <li><a href = "">Field Solution Portal</a></li>
                                <li><a href = "">Polaris</a></li>
                                <li><a href = "">Operational Analytics Request Form</a></li>
                                <li><a href = "">Requesting an Escalation for Polaris case</a></li>
                                <li><a href = "">Claims Available for Reporting</a></li>
                                <li><a href = "">Submitting Cases via Polaris</a></li>
                                <li><a href = "">Data Use Policy</a></li>
                                <li><a href = "">Operating Model</a></li>
                                <li><a href = "">Knowledge Solution</a></li>
                                <li><a href = "">Insight Delivery</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>

                <!-- Intro -->
                <section class="intro">
                    <header>
                        <h1>Market Analytics Client Support</h1>
                        <p>Market Analytics is the trusted advisor for analysis and reporting. </p>

                    </header>
                    <div class="content">
                        <!-- <span class="image fill" data-position="center"><img src="images/pic01.jpg" alt="" /></span> -->
                    </div>
                </section>

    </body>
</html>
```

And here is the CSS:

Since the code had too many rows this is the link for it:

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Mauliklm10/Sharepoint-Site/main/Sharepoint_Overhaul/assets/css/main.css

Or if the link does not work:

https://github.com/Mauliklm10/Sharepoint-Site.git

Sharepoint_Overhaul -> assets -> css -> main

Comment: I don't see you css! Very often it's because the header has an overflow hidden, and drop down either doesn't fire or close when pass the computed height of navbar (that depends of situation).

Comment: Could you try looking at the css now? Sorry about that I thought the raw version would be available via the link to everyone

Comment: Hello, ok I checked and tried to reproduced. I don't think it's coming from css at all. In fact it's a question of 4th row option or not. Seems there are dynamic elements injected in navbar. Example: "book of business" has 4 items in your html. In rendering you have 6 items: 2 elements are dynamically injected. Last one "resources" has 13 items dynamically injected. The problem of disapearance appears on those 2 which have their list dynamically modified at rendering. So I think you should search in your script, module why, not in css

Comment: It also happens on the Hub and Peer Benchmarking as well as Rebates and compliance, they all have more than 4 options and so by the time I am trying to click on the fifth option the dropdown disappears.

Comment: hello, it's bit hard for me to reproduce and try your code, it's bit long and I'm missing several files to fully test. I tried the following: as test only, I put an height to the nav>ul of 75vh (line 14 of css) -> no break! So as said in first comment it's coming from the "supposed" nav bar height computed by the browser. At a certain height browser consider you are not anymore "hover". That's a common problem. For now, except if others have other ideas, the only I've found to go around this kind of problem is to javascript code dropdown.

Comment: Hey Pier thanks for clarifying this, if it helps, the whole code repository is on github which you can access from here: https://github.com/Mauliklm10/Sharepoint-Site. And if possible could you please guide me towards how I would go about this using javascript? Thank you